# Heroku reject push project

Tags: django, heroku

i try to publish my python project but i have some issues can you help me ? i have requirements.txt also i add my git profile this is my first time with heroku i don't understand what is wrong i add my project on git repository and main branch i use python 3 this is my python project my project files and git files are in same level i tried something is i found on internet but it not worked for me

and this is heroku error :

```
 -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/python
-----> Python app detected
-----> No Python version was specified. Using the buildpack default: python-3.10.4
       To use a different version, see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
-----> Installing python-3.10.4
-----> Installing pip 22.0.4, setuptools 60.10.0 and wheel 0.37.1
-----> Installing SQLite3
-----> Installing requirements with pip
       Collecting APScheduler==3.9.1
         Downloading APScheduler-3.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (59 kB)
       Collecting asgiref==3.5.0
         Downloading asgiref-3.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
       Collecting beautifulsoup4==4.10.0
         Downloading beautifulsoup4-4.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
       Collecting bs4==0.0.1
         Downloading bs4-0.0.1.tar.gz (1.1 kB)
         Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
         Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
       Collecting certifi==2021.10.8
         Downloading certifi-2021.10.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (149 kB)
       Collecting cffi==1.15.0
         Downloading cffi-1.15.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (446 kB)
       Collecting charset-normalizer==2.0.12
         Downloading charset_normalizer-2.0.12-py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
       Collecting cryptography==36.0.1
         Downloading cryptography-36.0.1-cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_24_x86_64.whl (3.6 MB)
       Collecting distlib==0.3.4
         Downloading distlib-0.3.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (461 kB)
       Collecting Django==2.2.27
         Downloading Django-2.2.27-py3-none-any.whl (7.5 MB)
       Collecting django-filter==21.1
         Downloading django_filter-21.1-py3-none-any.whl (81 kB)
       Collecting django-js-asset==2.0.0
         Downloading django_js_asset-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (4.9 kB)
       Collecting django-mptt==0.13.4
         Downloading django_mptt-0.13.4-py3-none-any.whl (137 kB)
       Collecting djangorestframework==3.13.1
         Downloading djangorestframework-3.13.1-py3-none-any.whl (958 kB)
       Collecting drf-flex-fields==0.9.7
         Downloading drf-flex-fields-0.9.7.tar.gz (28 kB)
         Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
         Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
       Collecting drf-renderer-xlsx==0.4.5
         Downloading drf_renderer_xlsx-0.4.5-py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
       Collecting et-xmlfile==1.1.0
         Downloading et_xmlfile-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (4.7 kB)
       Collecting filelock==3.6.0
         Downloading filelock-3.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (10.0 kB)
       Collecting gunicorn==20.1.0
         Downloading gunicorn-20.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (79 kB)
       Collecting idna==3.3
         Downloading idna-3.3-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
       Collecting ldap3==2.9.1
         Downloading ldap3-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (432 kB)
       Collecting openpyxl==3.0.9
         Downloading openpyxl-3.0.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (242 kB)
       Collecting Pillow==9.0.1
         Downloading Pillow-9.0.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (4.3 MB)
       Collecting platformdirs==2.5.1
         Downloading platformdirs-2.5.1-py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
       Collecting pyasn1==0.4.8
         Downloading pyasn1-0.4.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (77 kB)
       Collecting pycparser==2.21
         Downloading pycparser-2.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl (118 kB)
       Collecting python-dateutil==2.8.2
         Downloading python_dateutil-2.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (247 kB)
       Collecting pytz==2022.1
         Downloading pytz-2022.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (503 kB)
       Collecting pytz-deprecation-shim==0.1.0.post0
         Downloading pytz_deprecation_shim-0.1.0.post0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
       Collecting requests==2.27.1
         Downloading requests-2.27.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (63 kB)
       Collecting six==1.16.0
         Downloading six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
       Collecting soupsieve==2.3.1
         Downloading soupsieve-2.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (37 kB)
       Collecting sqlparse==0.4.2
         Downloading sqlparse-0.4.2-py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
       Collecting tzdata==2022.1
         Downloading tzdata-2022.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (339 kB)
       Collecting tzlocal==4.1
         Downloading tzlocal-4.1-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
       Collecting urllib3==1.26.9
         Downloading urllib3-1.26.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (138 kB)
       Collecting virtualenv==20.14.0
         Downloading virtualenv-20.14.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (8.8 MB)
       Collecting whitenoise==6.0.0
         Downloading whitenoise-6.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
       Building wheels for collected packages: bs4, drf-flex-fields
         Building wheel for bs4 (setup.py): started
         Building wheel for bs4 (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
         Created wheel for bs4: filename=bs4-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl size=1272 sha256=1b9aa0ae1eb53ab61439cc713b4cd3634e11eacadde3f580901099bdff9485c5
         Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-n0iong8p/wheels/25/42/45/b773edc52acb16cd2db4cf1a0b47117e2f69bb4eb300ed0e70
         Building wheel for drf-flex-fields (setup.py): started
         Building wheel for drf-flex-fields (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
         Created wheel for drf-flex-fields: filename=drf_flex_fields-0.9.7-py3-none-any.whl size=14682 sha256=83b04e19d2af8aa588e19a76d2d51e53fd5e0ae3b91972f0bf96dc98ffa3c4b6
         Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-n0iong8p/wheels/d1/ae/ef/2a1b188db93bb648757e281df437793c2a389ae01ef599effb
       Successfully built bs4 drf-flex-fields
       Installing collected packages: pytz, pyasn1, drf-flex-fields, distlib, certifi, whitenoise, urllib3, tzdata, sqlparse, soupsieve, six, pycparser, platformdirs, Pillow, ldap3, idna, gunicorn, filelock, et-xmlfile, charset-normalizer, asgiref, virtualenv, requests, pytz-deprecation-shim, python-dateutil, openpyxl, Django, cffi, beautifulsoup4, tzlocal, djangorestframework, django-js-asset, django-filter, cryptography, bs4, drf-renderer-xlsx, django-mptt, APScheduler
       Successfully installed APScheduler-3.9.1 Django-2.2.27 Pillow-9.0.1 asgiref-3.5.0 beautifulsoup4-4.10.0 bs4-0.0.1 certifi-2021.10.8 cffi-1.15.0 charset-normalizer-2.0.12 cryptography-36.0.1 distlib-0.3.4 django-filter-21.1 django-js-asset-2.0.0 django-mptt-0.13.4 djangorestframework-3.13.1 drf-flex-fields-0.9.7 drf-renderer-xlsx-0.4.5 et-xmlfile-1.1.0 filelock-3.6.0 gunicorn-20.1.0 idna-3.3 ldap3-2.9.1 openpyxl-3.0.9 platformdirs-2.5.1 pyasn1-0.4.8 pycparser-2.21 python-dateutil-2.8.2 pytz-2022.1 pytz-deprecation-shim-0.1.0.post0 requests-2.27.1 six-1.16.0 soupsieve-2.3.1 sqlparse-0.4.2 tzdata-2022.1 tzlocal-4.1 urllib3-1.26.9 virtualenv-20.14.0 whitenoise-6.0.0
-----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
       Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "/tmp/build_94cceabe/manage.py", line 21, in <module>
           main()
         File "/tmp/build_94cceabe/manage.py", line 17, in main
           execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
           utility.execute()
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
           self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
           self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
           output = self.handle(*args, **options)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 188, in handle
           collected = self.collect()
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 114, in collect
           handler(path, prefixed_path, storage)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 342, in copy_file
           if not self.delete_file(path, prefixed_path, source_storage):
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 249, in delete_file
           if self.storage.exists(prefixed_path):
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 324, in exists
           return os.path.exists(self.path(name))
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 44, in path
           raise ImproperlyConfigured("You're using the staticfiles app "
       django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.
 !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
       See traceback above for details.
       You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
       Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
          $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

Comment: Have you set STATIC_ROOT and STATIC_URL in your settings?

Answer (score 0):

You must setting the STATIC_ROOT when the DEBUG=False or when production step in the settings.py

example

`STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')`

and make sure to put `Procfile` in the root of project

for completed step you can access [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/python-support)

**Procfile** contain

```
web: gunicorn <yourapp>.wsgi --log-file -
```

Good luck and keep coding

Comment: Thank you for answer  i did and it's accept but now when it finished push and i try to go my site give me application error can you help me about that ?

Comment: can you show the error code?

Comment: 2022-04-16T14:11:59.240434+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=fiyatakipp.herokuapp.com request_id=c781b971-3514-4a49-99fe-59416ebb56b5 fwd="xxxxxx" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-04-16T14:11:59.420419+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fiyatakipp.herokuapp.com request_id=29ad7b09-8eca-4b37-b283-c8dfaabdd017 fwd="xxxxxx" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Comment: make sure to setting your Procfile to 
`web: gunicorn cores.wsgi --log-file -`

Comment: actually i don't have a procfile i think this is reason of error